# Git diff shows changes but other editors do not show a change

Tags: git, compare

When I build my solution, my compiler builds dynamic files. The process requires us to check in these dynamic files/copy over them for further downstream process. By doing this however, I notice that when running "git status" or "git diff", it shows there are changes for some files. But when I open them with notepad++ or beyond compare and compare it to the original file, there are no changes.

This is causing confusion during PRs. Does git somehow treat a brand new file copied over the original file differently, like another object/blob? Therefore, causing this "bug"? Or am I not running a git command correctly to reflect the change?

[image: Git Diff Output]

[image: Beyond Compare Output]

Comment: `git diff` shows the files as if they had been completely written over from scratch... even without any real changes?

Comment: So the compiler is essentially rebuilding the exact same file. Then it copies it over the original. Then when I run git diff, I see it says there are 4 lines deleted. When I use notepad++ or beyond compare to double check, there are no lines modified.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `git diff` and `git status` on the original question?

Comment: Added both git diff and beyond compare output

Comment: And those lines that are showing up in color red are _not_ part of the file as it is on `HEAD`?

Comment: The red lines are originally part of the file. Double checked by having two folders cloned in separate locations. One of the folders I rebuild on then compared against the other. Both on same branch. Did a git reset and cleaned index to really make sure.

Comment: I had similar cases in the past where either whitespace (space to tabs) or line endings ( \r\n to \n ) changed. Not sure if it is the case in your case but you may want to enable showing non-printable characters in NP++

Comment: A terminal-window `git diff` uses red for deleted lines - so those four lines are in the left-side operand, but just not there at all in the right-side operand.

Comment: @RolandKreuzer Yes, I'm also checked line endings, also tested with --renormalize. No changes I can identify. Beyond compare would show green or red as well.

Comment: @torek If so, beyond compare should have seen the lines deleted too.

Comment: @JosephLuce that does seem odd. I trust Git's diff pretty well though: I suspect BC is looking at some files that *aren't* the ones in the commits in question, although how that is occurring is another question.